# kaminari/will_paginate both broken in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, will-paginate

I get the following error with will_paginate and a similar one with kaminari when I was only using kaminari. Will paginate has just been installed in addition to kaminari and the error persists with or without it.

> undefined method 'paginate' for # < ActiveRecord::Relation:0x6e629c8 >

I am also using active admin and added the following code to kaminari.rb in initializers

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.page_method_name = :per_page_kaminari
end
```

The error line:

```
@bookings = current_user.bookings.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Comment: I don't know a lot about `will_paginate`, but are you sure that `paginate` exists for `ActiveRecord::Relation`? In the [documentation](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki) at the end, it seems that the method with `ActiveRecord` is `page` and not `paginate`.

Comment: page is an alias for paginate. It's working now though. Don't know why. Restarted the server (not for the first time) and it worked.